# from json it is not returning the result

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp, servlets

This is  jsp code what is happening is when i submit the code it will call url of ajax function and executing that function also but when returning it will call to other url 
If i'm calling ajax from jsp that is going to that particular url and executing it after that it entering to the other url without returning the result

```
<form name="frm" action="createnewcatgoryBean.jsp" onsubmit="return validatenewcat()" method="post">
    <table style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 8px;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <div style="width: width:271px; color:red;" id="validate"></div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Category Name<span>:</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input id="cat" onblur="return validatenewcat()" type="text" name="category">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Quotations form<span>:</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="quotations">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Agreement form<span>:</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="agreement">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Payment form<span>:</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="payment">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ETI<span>:</span>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="eti">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="float:right; padding-top:15px">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="width: 60px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is the JavaScript code that includes the AJAX request:

```
function validatenewcat() {
    var category = document.getElementById("cat").value;
    if (category == "") {
        setTimeout(document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML = "!PLz Enter The Category Name", 2000);
        return false;
    } else {
        var url = "catnamecheck.do?id=" + category;
        xmlhttp.open("post", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var temp = xmlhttp.responceText;
                    obj = JSON.parse(temp);
                    alert(obj);

                    if (temp != "") {
                        document.getElementById("validate").innerHTML = "!PLz Enter The Unique Category Name";
                        document.getElementById("cat").focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

this my java code

```
public Map<String, String> catuniqecheck(String id) {
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    String sql=null;
    try{
        c = JDBCHelper.getConnection();
        if(c!=null)
        {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            sql="select * from catgory where catgoryname=?";
            ps1=c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps1.setString(1, id);
            ps1.execute();
            rs1=ps1.getResultSet();
            if(rs1.next())
            {
                System.out.println("insdide of the catuniqecheck");
                map.put("catgoryname",rs1.getString("catgoryname"));
            }
            return map;
        }   
       else
         {  
               System.out.println("DB connection Established");
               return null  ;
         }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
               return null  ;
        }
finally{
            JDBCHelper.close(rs1);
            JDBCHelper.close(ps1);
            JDBCHelper.close(c);
       }
}
```

this my servlet code

```
 Map<String, String> result =p1.catuniqecheck(id);
                if(result!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("inside success");
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    json.accumulateAll(result);
                    System.out.println("inside json"+json.toString());
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
                }
```

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense. Please rephrase it.

Comment: `var temp = xmlhttp.responceText;` should be `var temp = xmlhttp.responseText;` (with an s).

Comment: that is entering to the other url without returning data to the javascript plz help me

Comment: now i was just changed to var temp = xmlhttp.responseText; and  document.getElementById("cat").focus(); when i press second time it is calling to the other url plz help me thank u

Comment: try returning false from validatenewcat function

Comment: i was returning false from the function

Comment: actually when you are click submit button, at that time your javascript function is called and action "createnewcatgoryBean.jsp" is also executed

Comment: then how to avoid calling to that "createnewcatgoryBean.jsp" url plz explain me thanks

Comment: either make it action="#" or return false from function validatenewcat() at the end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36657/discussion-between-pritesh-shah-and-ranjith-vkit)

Comment: @ranjithvkit You're not returning false in the case that it executes the `else` block - you return false from the callback function of the AJAX call but that's an entirely separate function, executing at a later point, and has no bearing on anything else. You want the very last line of that `validatenewcat()` function to be `return false;`.

Comment: if i make my action # how can i able to submit value when the validation is over wht is happening is when i submit second time it calling that url properly but it is not returning it to javascript and calling to the other url

Comment: you can submit your form from your javascript. So make action="#" and once validated call document.getElementById("frm").submit();

Comment: which is the very last function in that can u plz tell me

Comment: how i will getting know the validation will complete it will be getting know when it send true right

Comment: submit your form inside  if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {} after validating response from ajax call

Comment: it is not coming to the  ajax in the second time i submit just it will go to the url and execute the other one thank u plz help me in false statement itself

Answer (score 0):

try with
`obj = JSON.parse("["+temp+"]")`
And then first response length
`alert(obj[0].length);

 alert(obj[0]);`
bcoz sometime response itself inside Square brackets like [{...}]